# Let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Find the number of ordered pairs $(Y,Z)$ such that $Y, Z\subset X$ and $Y\cap Z=\emptyset$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Basically the question is asking the number of ways in which 2 elements can be selected such that the order pair formed by them doesn’t have common elements

So if one element is picked from the 5, only 4 elements remain, and the pairs themselves can be arranged in two ways
$$\binom 51 \binom 41 2!$$ $$=40$$

The correct answer is $243$. What am I missing here?

Comment: You pick $1$ point out of $5$, then $1$ from the remaining and multiply by $2$, that's twice times the number of distinct pairs of **elements**. But you have to choose **subsets** not elements.

Comment: @Desperado  I suspect it should say $Y,Z \subset X$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what exactly do you mean by ‘picking subsets, not elements’? Isn’t an ordered pair made up of elements only?

Comment: No, the ordered pair could be $(\{1,2\}, \{3,4\})$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma aren’t those just two ordered pairs?

Comment: No it's an ordered pair of two disjoint subsets, as you are counting.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ok, that explains a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Label every point of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ by $1$ (goes into set $A$), $2$ (goes into set $B$) or $3$ (goes into neither).

Every labelling yields a good pair $(A,B)$ and vice versa.

So we have $3^5 = 243$ such pairs.

Comment: Does that account for each sets having no elements?

Comment: @Aditya yes, all labels $3$ corresponds to the pair $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$

Comment: No I meant does the question wording allow for empty sets?

Comment: @Aditya yes, they count too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But I think $Y=X$ and $Z=X$ are not allowed according to $\subset$